# Run a Gitlab-CI deploy job after any of the build jobs done

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# Pipeline 1
pipeline1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "This is pipeline 1"
  variables:
    VAR: "P1"  # Set VAR variable for pipeline 1
  when: manual

# Pipeline 2
pipeline2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "This is pipeline 2"
  variables:
    VAR: "P2"  # Set VAR variable for pipeline 2
  when: manual

# Deploy Stage (shared between all pipelines)
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This is the deploy stage, ${VAR}."
  needs:
    - pipeline1
    - pipeline2
```

I want to Run any of pipeline manually from pipelines page in Gitlab to set the `VAR`, then the deploy job run and echo it to me.

But `deploy` waits for all of the jobs in `build` stage to run before starting.

Comment: You have added condition "needs"  pipeline1 and pipeline2 in deploy stage thats why it will wait for both to finish. Can you confirm if you want deploy to start if any one of pipeline1 *or* pipeline 2 finishes?

Comment: Yes. I want it to run every time if and only if a single pipeline runs.

Answer (score 0):

All jobs which are specified in `needs` should be included into pipeline and should finish successfully (with default `allow_failure: false`). So in your case it is possible to exclude `pipeline1` or `pipeline2` job from pipeline via [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules) in combination with [needs:optional](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needsoptional):

```
pipeline-1:
  rules:
    - if: $INCLUDE_PIPELINE_1 == "true"
      when: manual

pipeline-2:
  rules:
    - if: $INCLUDE_PIPELINE_2 == "true"
      when: manual

deploy:
  needs:
    - job: pipeline-1
      optional: true
    - job: pipeline-2
      optional: true
```

With this configuration it will be possible to specify `INCLUDE_PIPELINE_1` or `INCLUDE_PIPELINE_2` variable manually before starting the pipeline to exclude corresponding job.